# The use of const char* vs. string literals

Tags: c++, linux, string, char, constants

I'm using an external Modbus library - written in C - to connect to a microntroller Modbus slave from a Linux machine, using a serial connection. I'm also using wxWidgets to create an application on the Linux machine, which runs a Modbus master in the background.

One of the Modbus functions accepts the name of the serial port the Modbus master should connect to. On my Linux machine, that's `/dev/ttyS4`. In the function that I'm using, the parameter type is defined as `const char*`. When I pass the parameter as a string literal, i.e. `"/dev/ttyS4"`, the function works fine. However when I first define a variable as follows:

`const char mbPort[] = {'/', 'd', 'e', 'v', '/', 't', 't', 'y', 'S', '4'};`

and then pass that variable to the function, it doesn't work - and I'm not sure why that is. When passing the variable in a similar fashion in Windows, it worked fine. In Windows, my `mbPort` variable looked as follows:

`const char mbPort[] = { '\\', '\\', '.', '\\', '\\', 'C', 'O', 'M', '5' };`

So now i'm not sure whether it's a mistake in my code, or whether this is related to the OS that i'm using. Here is the declaration of the Modbus function that I'm using:

```
modbus_t* modbus_new_rtu(const char *device, int baud, char parity, int data_bit, int stop_bit);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that `"/dev/ttyS4"` will be null terminated, while `{'/', 'd', 'e', 'v', '/', 't', 't', 'y', 'S', '4'}` isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. You are totally right, adding ```'\0'``` to the end of the my variable fixed the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the value `'\0'` to the end of your initializer lists. Maybe on some compiler builds, there just happens to be a zero after the data in memory, but you cannot rely on that fact.